# What does the "hello" property mean in db health indicator? (Spring Actuator)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, spring-boot-actuator

I enabled the DataSourceHealthIndicator in spring actuator, and now in the "health" endpoint I got :

```
{
   "status":"UP",
   "details":{
      "db":{
         "status":"UP",
         "details":{
            "database":"H2",
            "hello":1
         }
      },
      "diskSpace":{
         "status":"UP",
         "details":{
            "total":999528853504,
            "free":773661831168,
            "threshold":10485760
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I was wondering what the **"hello":1** means in the db infos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means database healthcheck.

The fake periodical query (f.e. `select 'hello' from dual` in Oracle) checks if database is still available from the application. In actuator `"hello":1` means that the last healthcheck was successful.

See https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/java?topic=java-spring-healthcheck